# Django display crossed tables

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have an event signup page where the participant insert's details upon signing up. Then in a view I am trying to display a listing of their name, title, and details. I am stuck trying to get the details field to display if there were any for the participant. Thank you.

```
######## Model - Events ########
class Event(models.Model):
    Event_ID = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    Event_Description = RichTextField(null=True, blank=True)
    Event_Category = models.ForeignKey(EventCategories, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Event_participants = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='events')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Event_Name


######## Model - Events ########
class Submission(models.Model):
    participant = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="submissions")
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    details = models.TextField(null=True, blank=False)
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True,primary_key=True, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.event) + ' --- ' + str(self.participant)


######## View ########
def single_event(request, pk):
    try:
        event = Event.objects.get(Event_ID=pk)
        submitted = Submission.objects.filter(event=event)
        submitted = list(submitted.values('participant','details'))
    except:
        return render(request, 'events/single-event.html', {"success":True,}, status=200)
    context = {'events':Event.objects.filter(Event_ID=pk), 'event':event, 'submitted':submitted}
    return render(request, 'events/single-event.html', context)


######## Template - single-event.html  ########
{% for event in events %}
    {% for user in event.Event_participants.all %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ user.profile.title }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ ??????????? }}</td>  #This is where i need help. I would like to display 'details' from the Submission model here
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code how you are passing context doesn't makes sense specially `'events':Event.objects.filter(Event_ID=pk), 'event':event`

Django ORM `get()` method will always expect to give you 1 results if there are more than 1 results it will give an error. So not sure what is your idea here for events and event. If you expect more than 1 value with same event id then use `filter()` otherwise use `get()`

**Try it like this:**

```
def single_event(request, pk):
    try:
        event = Event.objects.get(Event_ID=pk)
        participants = event.Event_participants.all()

        submissions = Submission.objects.filter(event=event)
        submissions_map = {submission.participant_id: submission.details for submission in submissions}

        for participant in participants:
            participant.submission_details = submissions_map.get(participant.id, "No details submitted.")

    except Event.DoesNotExist:
        return render(request, 'events/single-event.html', {"success": False}, status=404)

    context = {
        'event': event,
        'participants': participants,
    }
    return render(request, 'events/single-event.html', context)
```

**In your template file adjust like below:**

```
 {% for participant in participants %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ participant.profile.title }}</td>
    <td>{{ participant.first_name }} {{ participant.last_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ participant.submission_details }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The information is now showing however it is showing the entire query in my html and not just the data for the specific user. 
Example:  {1: 'Sample Details', 24: 'This is another Sample'} is showing in each of the two rows when what i am looking for is "Sample Details" to show for user 1 and "This is another Sample" for user 24

Comment: Make sure the ID you are passing in `single_event ` is correct ID.

Comment: I am passing a single pk (Event_ID) and only want one event on this page. On this page I then have a table that is showing the participants title, name, and details (details on when the participant can work, like "I can only stay until 7pm")

Comment: Provide your urls.py how you are handling the urls with ID.

Comment: url.py path('event/<str:pk>/', views.single_event, name='single_event'),

Comment: for clarification I did remove 'events':Event.objects.filter(Event_ID=pk), 'event':event from are now using your code block

Comment: I have updated the code as per your description. Check now